# Is it possible to remote desktop to a PC from multiple PCs synchronously?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server

I want to remote desktop from (e.g. 2 PCs) to multiple accounts in one PC that has multiple user accounts synchronously.

Is there any software to do this for me?

I tried RDM (Remote Desktop Manager) but it couldn't do it for me or I couldn't configure it properly.